# iteration through list with div id's

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Beispiel</title>
<style type="text/css">
.box {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Spielfeld"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var spielfeldX = 3;
var spielfeldY = 3;

var zug = 0;

function MouseClick(e) {
    this.onclick = undefined;
    zug++;
    if (zug % 2 == 0) {
        this.textContent = "X";
    }   else {
        this.textContent = "O";
    }
}
var list = new Array('ol', 'om', 'or', 'ml', 'mm', 'mr', 'ul', 'um', 'ur');
for (var y=0; y<spielfeldY; y++) {
    for(var x=0; x<spielfeldX; x++) {
            var box = document.createElement('div');
            box.setAttribute('id', list[]);
            box.className = 'box';
            box.style.left = (x*100)+'px';
            box.style.top = (y*100)+'px';
            document.getElementById("Spielfeld").appendChild(box);
            box.onclick = MouseClick;

    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I give the div's i created with the for x,y loop the id values of the array? I dont know what i have to type in the index of the array. Because, when i write x*y or x+y or something like that, there are only a few different numbers. I also tryed this code instead:

```
for (var y=0; y<spielfeldY; y++) {
    for(var x=0; x<spielfeldX; x++) {
        var box = document.createElement('div');
        for (i=0; list.length>i; i++) {
        box.setAttribute('id', list[i]);            
        }
        box.className = 'box';
        box.style.left = (x*100)+'px';
        box.style.top = (y*100)+'px';
        document.getElementById("Spielfeld").appendChild(box);
        box.onclick = MouseClick;

    }
}
```

But when i tryed this, the id's of the div's were only 'ur'. So I don't know how to get all values of the 'list'-array as values for the div-id's.

Comment: just add a counter, every time you create a box ->
var counter = 0;
for .............
    for .............
             box.setAttribute('id', list[counter]);
             counter++;

otherwise the formula is:
x*y + y to calculate which index you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're trying to map an 1 dimensional array onto a 2 dimensional field you have to take the offset into account (which is the length of the x-axis `spielFeldX`).

You will get the right index of your array by multiplying the x-axis length with the current y-axis and add the position x to it:

```
y * spielfeldX + x
```

```js
var spielfeldX = 3;
var spielfeldY = 3;

var zug = 0;

function MouseClick(e) {
    this.onclick = undefined;
    zug++;
    if (zug % 2 == 0) {
        this.textContent = "X";
    }   else {
        this.textContent = "O";
    }
}
var list = new Array('ol', 'om', 'or', 'ml', 'mm', 'mr', 'ul', 'um', 'ur');
for (var y=0; y<spielfeldY; y++) {
    for(var x=0; x<spielfeldX; x++) {
            var box = document.createElement('div');
            var index = y * spielfeldX + x;
            box.setAttribute('id', list[index]);
            // just for the example
            box.textContent = list[index];
            box.className = 'box';
            box.style.left = (x*100)+'px';
            box.style.top = (y*100)+'px';
            document.getElementById("Spielfeld").appendChild(box);
            box.onclick = MouseClick;

    }
}
```

```css
.box {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Beispiel</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Spielfeld"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to say, that i am very unexperienced and im a really beginner in javascript, so sorry for that maybe stupid question. But Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow.

You can use [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Remainder_assignment) to calculate x (column), use [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) combined with the index of the array and how many columns you have to calcultate y.

Then go through the array once with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate an array of divs from your list array.

You only need to provide the number of columns (x value) since the number of rows (y value) depends on the length of your list array and the number of columns.

```js
const createDiv = (id,x,y) => {
  var box = document.createElement('div');
  box.setAttribute('id', id);
  box.className = 'box';
  box.style.left = (x*30)+'px';
  box.style.top = (y*30)+'px';
  box.innerHTML = id;
  // box.onclick = MouseClick;//you can add the click
  return box;
}
const createGame = (list,x,y) =>
  list.map(
    (id,index)=>
      createDiv(
          id,//the id from list
          index%x,//calculate x
          Math.floor(index/x)//calculate y
      )
  );

const container = document.getElementById("Spielfeld");
createGame(//this returns an array of divs
  ['ol', 'om', 'or', 'ml', 'mm', 'mr', 'ul', 'um', 'ur'],
  3//3 columns
).forEach(//for each div, append it
  div=>
    container.appendChild(div)
);
```

```css
.box {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="Spielfeld"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have x * y data in an arr array in a single dimension and you are interested in the i'th "row" and j'th "column", then you will need the i * x + j item. The reason is that you will need to skip the first i rows (from row 0 to row i - 1) and each row has y elements and you need to skip then the firs j columns (from column 0 to column j).

Also, you will need to make sure that the ids of your tags are unique. Having the same id for two different tags makes your HTML invalid.